# Exception handling in C - making try catch work across functions

Tags: c, exception, try-catch, setjmp

I am writing an exception handling library in C and i ran into a bump:

```
#define TRY do{ jmp_buf ex_buf__; switch( setjmp(ex_buf__) ){ case 0:
#define FINALLY break; } default:
#define CATCH(x) break; case x:
#define ETRY } }while(0)
#define THROW(x) longjmp(ex_buf__, x)
```

In my current implementation of try catch throw, I won't be able to throw an exception from inside a method called from inside the try block because the jmp_buf variable is local. How would i make that possible?
I thought about a global variable but that would not allow me to have nested try catch blocks.

Comment: Id on´t think this is possible without modifying *all* functions and function calls you have. C simply has no exceptions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a global jump buffer, because it needs to be visible to your "clients". You could, for example, save the old jump buffer in a try block, and restore it after its use.

In general, I would *not recommend this approach at all*, though. Trying to retrofit features into a language is fraught with peril, not the least of which would be the following code:

```
for ;; { 
  TRY {
    if (someVar) {
      break;
    }
  }
  FINALLY {
    doIt()
  }
  ETRY
}
```

Comment: Agreed: it is not a good idea to try to implement Object-oriented specific features in `C`. If you "need" to do such a thing you probably had chosen the wrong language...

Comment: .. not that try/finally/catch has anything at all to do with object orientation. Which, incidentally, works just fine in C.

Comment: Just a reminder that C++ is implemented in C.... Anyways this is a library for homework that I am making since it has to be done in C and i don't like C. Good approach though. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Jean-LucNacifCoelho "C++ is implemented in C" - no. just no.

Answer (score 3):

Use a stack of `jmp_buf`'s.  Or better yet, use [the existing CII library](https://code.google.com/p/cii/source/browse/trunk/include/except.h), which has been designed, built, and tested for this purpose.

Comment: 1- Creating a local variable within a newly created scope suffices to save the context, as the compiler allows you to reuse variable names in different scopes. 2- "Use this already implemented library" is never a good answer.